# Fieldset Legend in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, asp.net, css, legend, fieldset

I'm pulling my hair out here.

I'm styling the front end of an ASP.NET built site, one of the sections is a fieldset with a legend, however this area looks totally different between IE, firefox and chrome. IE being by far the most off. I don't have the ability to load browser specific stylesheets with the way that this build is set up, but I can use css browser specific hacks in the one stylesheet.

This is how it looks in firefox: 
[image: Firefox screen capture]

This is how it looks in chrome:
[image: Chrome screen capture]

This is how it looks in IE:
[image: IE screen capture]

This is my html and css for the fieldset and legend:

```css
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelBloodPressureAlerts_UpdatePanelBloodPressureAlerts > fieldset,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelGlucoseAlerts_UpdatePanelGlucoseAlerts > fieldset,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelWeightAlerts_UpdatePanelWeightAlerts > fieldset,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelTemperatureAlerts_UpdatePanelTemperatureAlerts > fieldset,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelOxygenAlerts_UpdatePanelOxygenAlerts > fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #7a8dab;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 81%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelBloodPressureAlerts_UpdatePanelBloodPressureAlerts > fieldset > legend,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelGlucoseAlerts_UpdatePanelGlucoseAlerts > fieldset > legend,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelWeightAlerts_UpdatePanelWeightAlerts > fieldset > legend,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelTemperatureAlerts_UpdatePanelTemperatureAlerts > fieldset > legend,
#TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelOxygenAlerts_UpdatePanelOxygenAlerts > fieldset > legend {
  text-indent: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px\9;
  /* IE 8 and below */
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="FieldSetAlertsBloodPressureSystolic">
  <legend>
    Systolic

    <input id="TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelBloodPressureAlerts_CheckBoxBloodPressureSystolicAlertEnablement" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'TabContainerAlerts$TabPanelBloodPressureAlerts$CheckBoxBloodPressureSystolicAlertEnablement\',\'\')', 0)"
    checked="checked" name="TabContainerAlerts$TabPanelBloodPressureAlerts$CheckBoxBloodPressureSystolicAlertEnablement"></input>
  </legend>
  <div id="TabContainerAlerts_TabPanelBloodPressureAlerts_PanelBloodPressureSystolicAlerts">
    <div id="DivBloodPressureSystolicAlertSection">
      <div id="DivBloodPressureSystolicAlertNormalWrapper">…</div>
      <div id="DivBloodPressureSystolicAlertWarningWrapper">…</div>
      <div id="DivBloodPressureSystolicAlertCriticalWrapper">…</div>
      <div id="DivMultiSliderExtenderBloodPressureSystolicAlert">…</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I'm trying to make everything look like it does in firefox, but I'm starting to think there is going to be no way IE will let me do that, especially with the alpha I am using in my bg.

Comment: What is different here? They are surely not *totally* different. On first look, they look similar. On a closer look, the slider-like parts look different, but this is caused by something not disclosed in the code posted. The title of the question suggests that this is about the *legend*, whereas the text seems to say that the entire *fieldsets* are rendered differently.

Comment: I mean the legend on the fieldset, they are rendered differently between each one (firefox and chrome it is on top of the border whereas in IE it is under the border). The difference between the firefox and chrome is left margin related

Comment: So it’s not really *totally* different. I think you should try and reduce the problem to a much simpler case. The other content in the `fieldset` element seems to be irrelevant to the issue, and the issue would be easier to see with simpler styling (e.g., with black on white instead of colors with insufficient contrast). The problem probably relates to the varying implementations of `fieldset` and its interaction with CSS settings.

Comment: Correct, it's not _totally_ different, but the difference is enough for my client to be up in arms about it. I should have cleaned it up to better ask my question, but I just used a real life situation, I apologize. I've read that fieldsets are notorious for being a pain in the ass when styling legends with the intention of keeping cross browser consistency. I may just claim defeat and attempt to style it different with no legend. For some reason now, IE is completely ignoring my border-radius property on the fieldset after I have inline-blocked the legend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following css trick:

```css
fieldset > legend {
   height:30px; 
   position:absolute;
   margin-top:-10px;
   background:blue; 
}
```

The the height 30px is an example, and the blue should be replaced by the color of the tabs background.